# Ошибка при записи\извлечения из файла числа

Tags: java, android

Записываю ID в файл таким образом:

```
bufferedWriter.write(content.widgetID);
bufferedWriter.newLine();
```

А когда читаю и вывожу через лог:

```
String intd = bufferedReader.readLine();
Log.d("MyLOG", "reStore file2: " + intd);
```

Вижу вот что:(Скинул скрин, т.к. этот квадратик не копируется)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` у вас наверное - целое (`int`), в файл вы его записываете, как символ ([`BufferedWriter.write(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write%28int%29)), и потом читаете, как строку, состоящую из одного символа в виде младших двух байт от `id`.

Либо при записи пишите строковое представление числа в `id` (`bufferedWriter.write( Integer.toString( id ) )`, или при чтении используйте `bufferedReader.read()` если у вас `id` укладывается в 0-65535.

Если файл не обязательно должен быть текстовым, можете для записи и чтения использовать [`dataOutputStream.writeInt`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeInt%28int%29) и [`dataInputStream.readInt`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readInt%28%29).

Comment: Я так и думал, но когда я сделал `Integer.toString( id ))` Ошибка осталась, а на самом деле я просто не удалил прошлый файл, куда это записалось как байт. Спасибо за ответ